# Cannot SSH into server after sshd config change

Tags: ssh, sshd

I tried adding SFTP access to a second user in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Unfortunately I left a space between the usernames and later realized this might be the cause:

```
Match User user1, user2
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

After restarting sshd I cannot login to my server on Putty or even on the Lightsail interface.

Can someone please advise me on what to do next? Thanks

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @user68186 Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS as provided on Lightsail.

Comment: Your only choice may be to get help from Amazon as you don't have physical access to the physical server.

Comment: @user68186 thank you.